# What is the asp.net web api for image upload from Android (Retrofit)?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, file-upload, retrofit2

I want to upload image to server from Android. I have used retrofit library in Android part. How can I write a web api (asp.net), where I can retrieve the image, image name?

Android:

```
RequestBody requestBody;
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload;
RequestBody filename;



            File f = new File(getExternalCacheDir().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals(imageNewname)) {
                    f = temp;
                    ImageUri = f.toString();

                    textFilePath.setText(ImageUri);

                    requestBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),temp);
                    fileToUpload=MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",temp.getName(),requestBody);
                    filename=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),temp.getName());

                    break;
                }
            }




UploadPhotoApiInterface apiService = OperatingApiClient.getClient().create(UploadPhotoApiInterface.class);
Call<UploadPhotoApiResponse> call = apiService.getUploadPhotoInfo(fileToUpload,filename);
call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadPhotoApiResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UploadPhotoApiResponse> call, Response<UploadPhotoApiResponse> response) {
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UploadPhotoApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        // Log error here since request failed
        //Log.e(TAG,t.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface UploadPhotoApiInterface {

    @GET("NNGOperating/SaveAttachment")
    Call<UploadPhotoApiResponse>  getUploadPhotoInfo(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,@Part("file")RequestBody name);


}
```

What is the correct api for this api interface

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("~/SaveAttachment")]
        public object SaveAttachment()
        {

        }
```